# Dados repetidos no html (ANGULAR)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Tenho um *ngFor que preenche meu html, e esses dados são buscados de uma API, aí eu utilizo schedule pra recarregar os dados toda vez que dá segundos = 15.

Só que os dados estao sendo colocados abaixo dos antigos la no HTML.

***HTML:***

```
<p [class]="mainColor + ' teste' " *ngFor="let element of fil">Filial {{ element.FI }} = {{ element.porc }}</p>
```

***TS:***

```
  ngOnInit() {
        schedule.scheduleJob(' 15 * * * * * ', () => {      
          this.MetaService.FiliaisMetaDiarias().subscribe(
  data => {
    const response = (data as any)
    this.objeto_retorno = JSON.parse(response._body);

    this.objeto_retorno.forEach(element => {

      this.tots = element.TOTAL
      element.TOTAL = (element.TOTAL * 100).toFixed(3) + '%'
      element.TOTAL = element.TOTAL.toString().replace(".", ",")
      if (this.tots >= this.MetaAtingida) {

        this.fil.push({
          FI: element.FILIAL,
          porc: element.TOTAL
        });

        this.mainColor = 'MetaAtingida'

      }
        });
    }
```

Toda vez que o segundo é = 15 ele o código é recarregado e colocado no html, mas não ta apagando os dados anteriores que está no html.

Alguém sabe resolver isso?

Comment: O comportamento, me parece que se deve ao seu `this.fil.push()` se você está substiuindo os elementos, antes você deveria limpar ele.

Comment: Eu limpo o array, mas mesmo assim continua do mesmo jeito

Comment: Onde você limpa?

Comment: quando inicia a função do schedule

Comment: Era melhor usar o metodo filter e map que forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se assim funciona.

```
ngOnInit() {
        schedule.scheduleJob(' 15 * * * * * ', () => {      
          this.MetaService.FiliaisMetaDiarias().subscribe(
  data => {
    const response = (data as any)
    this.objeto_retorno = JSON.parse(response._body);

    this.fil.length = 0;

    this.objeto_retorno.forEach(element => {

      this.tots = element.TOTAL
      element.TOTAL = (element.TOTAL * 100).toFixed(3) + '%'
      element.TOTAL = element.TOTAL.toString().replace(".", ",")
      if (this.tots >= this.MetaAtingida) {

        this.fil.push({
          FI: element.FILIAL,
          porc: element.TOTAL
        });

        this.mainColor = 'MetaAtingida'

      }
        });
    }
```

Por alguma razão muito estranha, no JavaScript, você consegue "resetar" um array ao definir o seu tamanho como 0.

```js
var fil = [1,2,3];
//push esvaziar ou redefinir o tamanho.
fil.push(4);
console.log(fil);

//redefinindo o tamanho e fazendo novo push
fil.length = 0;
fil.push(5);

console.log(fil);
```